# Subsetting Polygons from Spatial Polygons object by slot

Tags: r, r-s4, r-sp

I have 'SpatialPolygons' object and I want to subset the polygons where @hole == FALSE and make a new object.

str(my_object) returns this:
[image: structure output of my SpatialPolygons object]

Using the code below predictably get 1 polygon at a time (or none if @hole == TRUE), but I am not able to subset multiple polygons from my object.

```
newSP <- aDis[aDis@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[[1]]@hole == FALSE]
```

I think my issue lies in that I don't know how to reference the second list "in general", i.e. take the items from list(Polygon) where @hole == FALSE. Leaving the second [[]] blank does not work.

P.S. sorry there is no reproducible example; I'm not sure exactly how to recreate this issue in a simple way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with `sapply`:

```
hasHole <- sapply(
  aDis@polygons[[1]]@Polygons,
  slot,
  "hole"
)
aDis@polygons[[1]]@Polygons[!hasHole]
```

It's unusual to have to resort to this sort of thing as an end user, though. I'm not familiar with this particular package --- are there no functions defined elsewhere in it that help you to access these slots?

Comment: Thanks for this. There don't seem to be ways to access the slots specifically, other than in a list of deprecated functions provided in the package documentation. Attempted use of the function gives a warning/suggestion to use *apply and the slot directly (much like you did). Also, discussion elsewhere in the documentation about the "hole" slot suggests that maybe it's only a semi-reliable method of identifying holes. Most other solutions provided for dealing with holes in polygons are work-around-y. 

I like your solution -- using it will help me improve my understanding and use of slots.